# Bypassing "Insecure Content Blocked" with Selenium Ruby script

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new with using Selenium in my Ruby script. Basically my script will make a get request to some url and log in. However my script is failing to send the email and log in automatically due to the Google Chrome pop up about insecure content blocked since one of the images on the page is using http and not https.

I was able to run the script successfully months ago however just recently when trying again, it is unable to proceed with logging in so I dont know why it stopped working all of a sudden.

The error that I see in terminal is this. In irb, I can go through each line of code successfully including using Selenium's "send_keys" and "click" to automatically sign in.

[2018-09-26T13:02:55.002527 #14131]  INFO -- : [#http://company.com/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.">]
web_app.rb:54:in `': Console Errors Found! (Exception)

I tried searching for some solution but have been unsuccessful. There has been some variations of responses to similar problem but not too much luck with getting it to work.

Any feedback on how to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: Going to ask the obvious questions: have you tried just catching this error and ignoring it?  Does it not always happen on the same line of code?

Comment: As a corollary to my previous comment: I'm not finding anything that automatically throws exceptions on console errors with Selenium.  Are you sure you're not throwing this error yourself?

Comment: I figured out the problem and wasn't related to mixed content at all. Thanks.

Comment: you should write an answer to your question outlining how you solved the problem so that other people who may encounter this know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

start Chrome manualy and disable the warning - https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-insecure-content-warning-chrome

and use the set browser profile, there is my setup:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pburgr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();}
```